# OpenHaptics not compliling

Tags: c++, lnk2019

So I am new to c++ and over the last few days I have been attempting to get a program to compile. I downloaded OpenHaptics for my phantom OMNI and have been attempting to get a simple sphere program to compile. There errors it is giving me are as follows (I am using Visual c++ 2010)

I think the problem is that it might not be reading a glut32.dll file (based on internet research) how do I add this .dll file so that the compiler sees it, or if there is another problem how do i fix it?

```
------ Build started: Project: Spheretest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void     __cdecl qhStart(void)" (__imp_?qhStart@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QHRenderer::tell(class Cursor *)" (__imp_?tell@QHRenderer@@QAEXPAVCursor@@@Z) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Cursor::Cursor(void)" (__imp_??0Cursor@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QHRenderer::tell(class Sphere *)" (__imp_?tell@QHRenderer@@QAEXPAVSphere@@@Z) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall Sphere::Sphere(void)" (__imp_??0Sphere@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QHRenderer::tell(class DeviceSpace *)" (__imp_?tell@QHRenderer@@QAEXPAVDeviceSpace@@@Z) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall DeviceSpace::DeviceSpace(void)" (__imp_??0DeviceSpace@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
Sphereguts.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QHGLUT::QHGLUT(int,char * * const)" (__imp_??0QHGLUT@@QAE@HQAPAD@Z) referenced in function _main
MSVCRTD.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16 referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
C:\Users\Ryan Grainger\Desktop\c++ test\Spheretest\Debug\Spheretest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Sounds like you are not linking to the OpenHaptics library.

Comment: Well I got fed up with open haptics not working, so I basically have one folder now with everything in it that I'm linking to.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are listing the `.lib` files for the library you are linking-in.

Also... There's no `main()` in your source code. Or, rather, there's no `Windows`-specific analog called `WinMain()` - and the linker doesn't like it.

You need to provide the `WinMain()`, or build a non-`Windows` executable (just a `console application`?), or include all the necessary files into your solution (the set of files must contain the one with the `WinMain()` function in it)

Comment: here is my source code in two posts

#include <QHHeadersGLUT.h>//Include all necessary headers


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 
 QHGLUT* DisplayObject = new QHGLUT(argc,argv);//create a display window
 return 0;
}

Comment: DeviceSpace* Omni = new DeviceSpace;//Find the default Phantom Device
    DisplayObject->tell(Omni);//Tell Quickhaptics that omni exists
    
    Sphere* SimpleSphere = new Sphere;//Get a sphere
    DisplayObject->tell(SimpleSphere);//Tell Quick Haptics that the sphere exists

    Cursor* OmniCursor = new Cursor;//Create a cursor
    DisplayObject->tell(OmniCursor);//Tell QuickHaptics that a cursor exists
    
  
    qhStart();//Set everything in motion

Comment: Also there are two versions of the source code I am trying to compile, the first is for GLUT and the second is for Win32

Comment: Don't add your source to the comments. If it's relevant then update the question.